# Notification & WebViewBounce option not working - Phonegap

Tags: jquery, ios, cordova, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm creating my app on Phonegap Build, at the current version (2.3.0) and I got two problems:

The notification and WebViewBounce (I'm trying to disable) do not work.

I tried to use on config.xml:

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
<!-- Plugins -->
<plugins>
<plugin name="Notification" value="CDVNotification" />
</plugins>
```

I have tried it on iOS 6.1.2 and was not successfull. Does anyone know how to get it working?

Thanks since now.

Comment: I just added <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script> to my index.html and now the Notification is working. 

I'm still having problem about the WebViewBounce.

Answer (score 4):

PhoneGap's config file (inside www/config.xml) came with this preference setting:

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="true" />
```

Which I assumed you would set to false to fix, however this wasn't working. After some digging around I found that you need to set `DisallowOverscroll` to true for iOS and `disallowOverscroll` to true for Android. So my config file now contains:

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
<preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

To cover all eventualities.

I also noted that I needed to remove height=device-height from my viewport meta tag. So before I had:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, 
maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, 
height=device-height, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
```

Which I changed to:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, 
maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, 
target-densitydpi=medium-dpi" />
```

Without doing this, my 100% height was including the status bar (or in call status bar which is slightly higher) in its height. Removing this value removed the scroll bar completely.

I then use divs within my app with `overflow: auto` if I need a scroll bar.

Comment: webviewbounce has been deprecated in favour of DisallowOverscroll. As of Cordova 3.6.3, neither will work on Windows Phone, they are completely ignored on that platform.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:  `<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>` to your HTML, as well.

Comment: Hi @pennstump, thanks for your suggestion. I just tried your code, but it didn't work.

Comment: `cordova.js` is something for manually building PhoneGap.  The OP mentioned PhoneGap Build, which uses `phonegap.js`.  It's possible that adding `cordova.js` could do something, but I don't think it's necessary for the built-in functionality.